# How to access Big Map value for a specific key

Tags: bigmap

I am trying to access big_map data for a specific key, but I found that I need to provide the hash of the key to retrieve the data. Is there  a way to get the hash for a key? Knowing the algorithm used to generate the key should be good enough too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick way (using Pytezos library):

```
>>> from pytezos.michelson.pack import get_key_hash
>>> get_key_hash({"string": "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn"}, {"prim": "address"})
'exprvAHu1SyoiSzyh9w7GPfifvyrNiMb442y7Q2MA8tcPCGPajxRH6'
```

Where first argument is the key (Micheline JSON), and the second one is the expression type (Micheline JSON).

Here is the algorithm and intermediate results (for value/type used above):

1. Pack key (e.g. using **pack_data** [RPC endpoint](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-scripts-pack-data))
   `050a0000001601a3d0f58d8964bd1b37fb0a0c197b38cf46608d4900`
2. Take **Blake2b** hash (digest size = 32)
   `d8a60c00b3c8f62cc2b3b8006b1858a621b5b74e06d3c82916659beaa24c8f67`
3. Prepend **"0d2c401b"**
   `0d2c401bd8a60c00b3c8f62cc2b3b8006b1858a621b5b74e06d3c82916659beaa24c8f67`
4. **Base58** encode with checksum
   `exprvAHu1SyoiSzyh9w7GPfifvyrNiMb442y7Q2MA8tcPCGPajxRH6`

Comment: Thanks @michael for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using ConseilJS for this. I used the `TezosMessageUtils.encodeBigMapKey` function in ConseilJS to create the hash key. Here's an example of how to convert the key to the hash :

```
const packedKey = TezosMessageUtils.encodeBigMapKey(Buffer.from(TezosMessageUtils.writePackedData(secretHash, "bytes"), "hex"));
```

You need to put the appropriate type of your key in the `writePackedData` before encoding it.