# What is script_expr?

Tags: rpc, bigmap

The RPC for querying big maps mentions [script_expr](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-big-maps-big-map-id-script-expr), but no where else in the [Tezos Developer Documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/index.html) is it mentioned.

- What is script_expr?
- Where can developers learn more about it?
- What libraries support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is script_expr?

Prior to the Babylon protocol, a contract could only have one big map. This big
map had to be located in a storage structured like this: `or (big_map ...) ...`.
There is a deprecated
[route](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/rpc.html#post-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-big-map-get)
to query a big map in the location.

Since Babylon, a contract can have multiple big maps. Each of these big maps have a unique
id (an integer). Using this [route](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-big-maps-big-map-id-script-expr),
you can query the key of a particular big map. However, you must prepare the key data in
a particular format of Michelson called `script_expr`.
It is the Blake2B hash of packed data that is then encoded into Base58.

Here is an example copied from this [answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2820/446).

We want the `script_expr` for an address `KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn`.

1. Pack the key (this is available in the RPC, the tezos-client and various libraries).
   `050a0000001601a3d0f58d8964bd1b37fb0a0c197b38cf46608d4900`
2. Hash it with Blake2B hash and digest size of 32.
   `d8a60c00b3c8f62cc2b3b8006b1858a621b5b74e06d3c82916659beaa24c8f67`
3. Prepend "0d2c401b".
   `0d2c401bd8a60c00b3c8f62cc2b3b8006b1858a621b5b74e06d3c82916659beaa24c8f67`
4. Base58 encode the result with checksum.
   `exprvAHu1SyoiSzyh9w7GPfifvyrNiMb442y7Q2MA8tcPCGPajxRH6`

From the command line you can do:

```
tezos-client hash data '"KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn"' of type address

Script-expression-ID-Hash: exprvAHu1SyoiSzyh9w7GPfifvyrNiMb442y7Q2MA8tcPCGPajxRH6
```

> Where can developers learn more about it?

This first part should cover most of what a developer needs to know about
`script_expr` if they need to implement in a library. However, if you
need more information it is best to start looking at the source code.

You need to understand how [pack](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/master/src/proto_008_PtEdoTez/lib_protocol/script_interpreter.ml#L1075) works. Blake2B in the tezos source code comes from [digestf](https://github.com/mirage/digestif) which
is an OCaml wrapper around the [High Assurance Cryptographic Library](https://hacl-star.github.io/).
Then you can see where [script_expr](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/25ef09bfa652f72f23d2e0ba2dfc955d7cb5be57/src/proto_002_PsYLVpVv/lib_protocol/script_expr_hash.ml) is defined.

> What libraries support it?

These libraries all support packing and have Blake2B and Base58 tools as
dependencies. You can follow the example in the first section.

- [ConseilJS](https://github.com/Cryptonomic/ConseilJS)
- [taquito](https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito)
- [pytezos](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos)

Answer (score 1):

`script_expr` in this RPC means any Michelson expression. It is used to specify the key of the big_map that the RPC queries.

Comment: What is the expected format of `script_expr`? I don't imagine it is going to read `PUSH nat 3; PUSH address "tz1..."; PAIR`? And where can developers learn more about it?

Comment: Assuming from your comment that your big map is indexed by keys of type `pair address nat`, you can build the expression as follows: `$ tezos-client convert data 'Pair "tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx" 3' from Michelson to JSON`.